# starting elasticsearch instance from java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to manage starting and stopping of elasticsearch from Java. Is there any easy/nice way to do this?

We're trying to deploy ElasticSearch in our product and we want to maintain the instance of the ElasticSearch on our customer's machine in our own product, and right now every thing depends on having an ElasticSearch instance started from es.bat or something.

As an aside, can anyone give me an example of how to mock test some code around the Jest API for ElasticSearch, so I can unit test our stuff that calls ElasticSearch without needing to start an ElasticSearch instance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting an elasticsearch instance is extermely easy. You just have to use the [Java API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/). That means you have to add the elasticsearch dependency to your project and create a node, as mentioned in the [reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/client/):

```
// on startup
Node node = nodeBuilder().node();
Client client = node.client();

// on shutdown
node.close();
```

Once you created the node it will behave exactly the same as a node started from the command line. You can interact with it using the created client object, but by default it will also open the 9200 and 9300 (or following ones if busy) ports for rest calls and inter-node communication.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had assumed that that needed an ElasticSearch started up to connect to it, hence Client, but building the node makes sense...great! I'll be able to try it soon. Glad it's easier than I thought.

Comment: You'll see yourself how easy it is :) YOu may want to upvote/accept your answer after you made sure it was useful. ;)

Comment: If you don't have the static import, NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()

Comment: It's not supported in 5.x, however you can still get it to work unofficially: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298467/how-to-start-elasticsearch-5-1-embedded-in-my-java-application/41299436#41299436