# Starting Elastic Search from java and not form any batch file

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash

I ma totally new to this . . . I want to start Elastic search by java code say by a main method

```
 `Node node = nodeBuilder().local( true ).node();
        Client client = node.client();
        node.start();`
```

I used the above code to run it which runs without error but it stops after two seconds only thing that i see in console is

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.elasticsearch.node).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Kindly help guys and here is the link of a similar question but it dint helped

[starting elasticsearch instance from java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498853/starting-elasticsearch-instance-from-java)

Comment: add BasicConfigurator.configure() to your code before instantiating the Client so that you can provide the error message that's causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing else to your code, the issue is that the ES thread on it's own won't keep the program alive.  You need to have a thread of your own to keep it alive.. for example:

```
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().local(true).node();
    node.start();
    while (!node.isClosed()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            node.close();
        }
    }
    node.stop();
```

Comment: Thanks @Alcanzar it worked for me  . . . but wondering if there is anything else like START and STOP mechanism . . . that would really help. Thanks again

Comment: not quite sure what you are asking... if you need something that can act like /etc/init/rc.d scripts, the ES RPM packages come with all of that.

Comment: what  i mean is my Java Code should be able to start() and stop() ES not from scripts. Something very similar to the snippet you wrote . . .  if only the THREAD part can be  removed that is exactly what i want.

Comment: you can do whatever you want between the node.start() and node.stop().  This was just an example showing you had to do SOMETHING.

Comment: I am working with logstash which requires an ES instance running. That is why I was wondering if i can keep the ES instance UP and stop by some other method call on a specific condition.  NOTE: I cannot use embedded ES which comes with Logstash

Comment: you could definitely do "pool mans IPC" and just have a loop in your code that sayes `while (someFile.exists()) { Thread.sleep(1000); }` and then just remove the file when you want the process to shut down (and the sleep 1000 would make it check once a second).