# running elasticsearch from java code

Tags: windows, jakarta-ee, elasticsearch, cmd

I want to run elastic search from a servlet.
   I use this method in my servlet to run elasticsearch but it does not seem to work.

```
ejbsessionbean.runcommand( "cmd C:\\ELK\\elasticsearch\\bin\\elasticsearch";)
```

The code for runcommand follows:

```
  public  static void runcommand(String ch) throws IOException {

   if (ch.length() <= 0) {
     System.err.println("Need command to run");
   System.exit(-1);
      }

         Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
   Process process = runtime.exec(ch);
   InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
   String line;

   System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", 
       ch);

   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
   }
```

}

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work?

Comment: the elasticsearch dosn't start (i enter in my browser  localhost:9200 and i get nothing )

Comment: Do you see any log output?

Comment: entering TestServlet doGet method... 

17:57:41,350 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-19) Output of running cmd  C:\ELK\elasticsearch\bin\elasticsearch.bat is:Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]

17:57:41,350 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-19) Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits r‚serv‚s.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498853/starting-elasticsearch-instance-from-java